# `.replaceChild()` on `this` Throwing NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8

Tags: javascript, jquery

I figured I would get fancy and use vanilla JavaScript during a jQuery event.  The idea is that on click of a heading, I want to slide up a div (which works) and replace the tag clicked on to a larger heading.

From what I've read around, this can be caused by the `parentNode` referencing an element that's not the actual parent, but after checking it appears to be selecting the element that's directly above it.

So... here's the code!

## HTML (in Jade)

```
.policy-container
  h6.policy-heading Policies
  .policy-list
    .content-we-are-hiding
    .not-actually-important
```

## jQuery

```
$('.policy-heading').click(function() {
    var self = this;

    if (this.classList.contains('closed')) {
        $(this).next().slideDown(300);

        this.parentNode.replaceChild(self, '<h6 class="policy-heading">Policies</h6>');

    } else {
        $(this).next().slideUp(300);

        this.parentNode.replaceChild(self, '<h2 class="policy-heading closed">Policies</h2>');
    }
});
```

Everything seems pretty standard.  Luckily I can just take care of this with jQuery, however I'd rather be using vanilla JS here.  Any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: The `replaceChild` method's first parameter should be the **new** node to insert, and the second is the node to be replaced. Emphasis on the word **node** for both - a string isn't a node

Comment: Yep, had my arguments backwards/ didn't create elements for what I was replacing the values with.

Comment: @Ian - you saved the day for me! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been pointed out, `replaceChild` takes two nodes.

The following will work with native JS wrapped inside jQuery, as you've specified:

```
$('.policy-heading').click(function () {
    var self = this,
        h2 = document.createElement('h2'),
        h6 = document.createElement('h6');

    h2.class = "policy-heading closed";
    h2.innerHTML = "Policies";

    h6.class = "policy-heading";
    h6.innerHTML = "Policies";

    if (this.classList.contains('closed')) {
        $(this).next().slideDown(300);
        this.parentNode.replaceChild(h6, self);
    } else {
        $(this).next().slideUp(300);
        this.parentNode.replaceChild(h2, self);
    }
});
```

Comment: Close, you have the arguments backwards for `replaceChild()`.  This, along with the fact I had to do the `document.createElement()` for the replacing elements was the issue.  I'll write up what code I actually used then accept one of these answers.

Comment: If you're going to suggest using jQuery for everything else, at least use it for the specific problem - `.replaceWith()`

Comment: @Dropped.on.Caprica No, but I guess it applies to the OP and all the answers. Stick with the reliable jQuery method that does exactly what is needed **and** doesn't require nodes

Comment: @DerekHenderson Sure it does. The OP was asking how to replace an element with another (in this case, using a string), which `.replaceWith()` would just fine with

Comment: FWIW, I created a jsPerf test (http://jsperf.com/jquery-replacewith-versus-native-replacechild) and it's marginally faster to inject the native JS, if that tiny amount is important to you.  ;)

Comment: @DerekHenderson I'm sure it's faster, basically **all** DOM methods are faster than using jQuery. But if you're going to argue that, then you shouldn't be suggesting jQuery in your answer at all...

Comment: Nevermind, I forgot seeing the `Luckily I can just take care of this with jQuery, however I'd rather be using vanilla JS here.` in the OP

Comment: @Ian Not sure what the advantages are of using jQuery over regular JavaScript is in this situation.  I've just trying to ween myself off using shortcuts with jQuery (I was using `.replaceWith()` for my jQuery solution).  Keep to using the "good parts" of jQuery (event delegation, $.ajax, sizzle selector, etc.)

Comment: @Dropped.on.Caprica Advantages? How about memory leaks? You remove an element with DOM methods and the jQuery handlers/data can't be cleaned up. `.replaceWith()` internally cleans up a lot of stuff, as well as other methods like `.html()`, `.text()`, `.empty()`, and `.remove()`

Comment: @DerekHenderson Thanks for the jsPerf.  One thing that's misleading is that you are using `document.createElement` in both examples.  From what I understand that is where you see the main performance increase in jQuery vs. JS.

Comment: @Ian Ahh, I didn't know that, thanks for letting me know.  Do you know of a way of checking events bound to the specific DOM element?  I'm using a `.on()` for my events, so in my particular situation I wouldn't think I'd run into events being lost in memory space.

Comment: @Dropped.on.Caprica Also, it allows you to pass an HTML string instead of having to create the element(s) yourself

Comment: @Dropped.on.Caprica, yes, I always create my elements using `document.createElement`. Since I used it for both examples, it doesn't throw off the results.  That test was only for `$.replaceWith()` versus `node.replaceChild`.

Comment: @Dropped.on.Caprica And just so you know, jQuery doesn't actually use `.replaceChild()` when you call `.replaceWith()` - it uses the DOM method `.insertBefore()` and then the jQuery method `.remove()`. Not sure of the reason, but it's an example of why I'd let jQuery handle this

Comment: @Ian Very interesting.  Definitely gave me a few things to think about, thanks for your input.  I should get around to reading their [annotated source](https://github.com/robflaherty/jquery-annotated-source) to get a feel on why they do some of the things they do.

Comment: @Dropped.on.Caprica To get events bound with jQuery, you can use `jQuery._data( elem, "events" );` where `elem` is a DOM element. To remove these, you could loop through the keys (event names) of what's returned and use `.off()`. To clear its data, you can use: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.removeData/

Comment: @Ian Sweet, thanks a lot.  [I guess I could have always searched.](http://bit.ly/pILk1r)

Comment: @Dropped.on.Caprica No problem. And we can pretend like I never told you and you found it yourself :)

Comment: Please clean up the comments that are no longer relevant (questions answered, clarifications addressed). If you have clarifications, please put them in the appropriate place (question clarifications should be edited into the question).

Answer (score 1):

`replaceChild` takes two nodes, you are giving it a node and a string.

It looks like you'd be much better off just sticking with jQuery and using toggle functions for the sliding and class change.

Comment: I'm not changing classes, I'm changing heading tags (from `<h6></h6>` to `<h2></h2>`.  I understand I'll have to eventually use .on() events.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

`.click(function(this)`

you also need some debugging to understand what is going on I would advice you to use :

`console.log(this)`

use this :

```
el = document.createElement('h6');
el.class = "policy-heading";
el.innerHTML = "Policies";

this.parentNode.replaceChild(self, el);
```

Comment: This isn't going to fix the issue, I understand the difference between `this` and the jQuery event.

Comment: your `$('.policy-heading')` is probably returning an array. try to use evt.srcElement

Answer (score 1):

As everyone pointed out, `.replaceChild` accepts two DOM elements, rather than the string like I was using.  I also had its arguments backwards, the first is for the new element, the second is the replaced element.

## Example code that works

```
$('.policy-container').on('click', '.policy-heading', function() {

    var self = this,
            newElement;

    if (this.classList.contains('closed')) {

        newElement = document.createElement( 'h6' );
        newElement.classList.add('policy-heading');
        newElement.innerHTML = 'Policies';

    } else {

        newElement = document.createElement( 'h2' );
        newElement.classList.add('policy-heading');
        newElement.classList.add('closed');
        newElement.innerHTML = 'Policies';

    }

    $(this).next().slideDown(300, function() {
        self.parentNode.replaceChild( newElement, self );
    });

});
```